# How to load-balance among two docker services?

Tags: node.js, docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm, netflix-eureka

- I Have docker-service (Node.js)

  - I am calling this service through API-gateway (spring-boot) using **zuul routes**.
  - I run the service on 2 different port and name of that 2 microservice is also different.
  - The internal name of the service is same and using the same name it enrolls on Eureka.

[image]

[image]

- I want to perform a Load balance on this service so that few request can serve by 1st service and few by 2nd.

I am running this service using below command

```
sudo docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network ${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

Is there something that I can configure for load-balance in command itself or any alternative ??

Comment: The more lazy way is to use the `jwilder-nginx` image.

Answer (score 4):

Use a load balancing server to choose between each instance.
The choice of load balancer is up to you, but here is the config for an NGINX balancer:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:123;
    server 127.0.0.1:124;
}

server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

This defines a set of `upstream` servers which NGINX chooses between when loading pages. NGINX will keep track of the state of each server, and avoid making requests to ones which are offline / erroring.

You could make a docker instance of NGINX which acts as a load balancer for the other instances

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html